# What does "in accord with" mean in this conext?

Tags: sentence-construction, word-meaning

> Types 2)–4) are fundamentally different from plebiscites. In those
> cases, a pre-defined class of government decision is always subject to
> a constitutionally required (mandatory) referendum;, or and citizens
> can, by petition, challenge government decisions (optional referenda)
> or even hand in their own proposals for constitutional or legislative
> reform (popular initiatives). The difference is that all these devices
> sanction or correct government policies and politics even when the
> government might not wish for popular interference. Under these
> institutional arrangements, direct democracy thus gives citizens an
> independent voice in politics and policies. This may be **in accord with
> governmental policies**, especially in the case of constitutionally
> required referenda. But the voice of the citizens can be, and often
> is, also raised against the government. To challenge government
> decisions in a selective way is the ‘natural’ use of popular
> referenda. The idea of ‘correcting’ representative democracy is
> further developed by the popular initiative, which allows the people
> to not only approve or reject government decisions, but also offers a
> group of citizens the chance to have their own propositions put to a
> popular vote.
>
> *- Swiss Democracy by Wolf Linder*

I don't understand what does "in accord with" mean in this context?
Does it mean: it is in favour of government in constitutionally required referenda cases?

Answer (score 1):

In accord with means agreeing with. In this case the sentence means that the citizens' voice may agree with government policies, and this is more likely for constitutionally required referenda.